# SQLDataReader.Close doesn't close immediately

Tags: sqldatareader

I am using a SQLDataReader to read a limited number of rows from a table so that I can page them into a gridview. Once I have read the number of rows I want, I want to exit; however the Reader.Close (or Reader.Dispose) does not return immediately.

I am doing this to show comparisons of various ways of reading data, so I am not looking for alternative solutions. I simply want to exit the code when I have the desired number of rows.

Here is the code:

```
SqlDataReader Reader = null;
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZipData"].ConnectionString);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ZipCode", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("City", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

try
{
    string Query = string.Format("{0} WHERE ZipCode Like @ZipCode AND City Like @City AND State Like @State ORDER BY {1}", SQLQuery, (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType)) ? "ZipCode" : sortType);
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
    Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", filter.Zip + "%"));
    Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@City", filter.City + "%"));
    Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@State", filter.State + "%"));

    Connection.Open();
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
    int CurrentRow = 0;
    DataRow row;
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        if (CurrentRow >= startRowIndex)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > maximumRows) break;
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["ZipCode"] = (string)Reader["ZipCode"];
            row["City"] = (string)Reader["City"];
            row["State"] = (string)Reader["State"];
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        CurrentRow++;
    }
    Reader.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    Connection.Close();
}
return dt;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at Microsoft's documentation, you can speed up closing the connection by cancelling the sql command.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx

So, you should be able to add this prior to closing to achieve your desired outcome.
Command.Cancel()

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't want alternate solutions, but why not use SELECT TOP 200 or whatever maximumRows is in the SQL? This would improve just about everything; less load on SQL Server, network, and local computer...

After testing your code, I didn't see a problem with closing the reader nor connection. Can you better describe the issue?

Comment: The ZipCodes file has 87,000++ rows. If I select top N *, a sort or filter doesn't find all the rows. If I select *, the Reader.Close() line pauses for up to 15 seconds. My SQL connection is over a T1 VPN link, so if you were to test this where SQL Server is very close, you might see this issue.